# Webbrowser and Hardware back button in Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

My Wp7 app failed to get a certification in the marketplace because I am loading a webpage in a WebBrowser at the startpage of my application and it loads three pages(webpage) one after other and every page has two popups.The testing team in market place are expecting the onbackkeypress (hardware back button) to close the popup whenever its open instead of closing webbrowser.I tried webbrowser.invoke but it failed because while am in second webpage and the popup is open webbrowser.invoke makes the page to reload and comes back to the first webpage.please instruct me!